# Why won't my jquery button disable

Tags: jquery, button, disable-link

I'm trying to disable a button if the user is currently on that page, I know there is more efficient ways but i am practicing my if, elses.

The problem is that I am still able to click the links and both will refresh the page if I click them and i'm on the same page. My code:

```js
$("#homepage").on("click", function(event) {
    if (window.location.href === 'index.html') {
        $(this).attr('disabled', "disabled");
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        event.preventDefault();
    }else {
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
    };
}); 
$("#aboutUs").on("click", function(event) {
    if (window.location.href === 'aboutus.html') {
        $(this).attr('disabled', "disabled");
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        event.preventDefault();
    }else {
        window.location.href = 'aboutus.html';
    };
});
```

Comment: Log what `window.location.href` is. It will never be `'index.html'`

Comment: check `console.log(window.location.href)` and see what its output. i think it's something different and that's why `if` condition never succeed.

Comment: @AlivetoDie In Google Chrome, for example, it will be `file://C:\Users\admin\Desktop\MyWebsite\index.html` when loaded up. It will be like `https://www.example.com/index.html` on a server, or on a regular IP address, `142.153.31.22/index.html` and never **just** "index.html"

Comment: so am i reading this right that there is no way to do it this way without hosting it first to get a specific link?

Comment: @ChristianA  use `indexOf()` like below(in my answer). Check and let us know worked or not?

Comment: both ways worked index0f and specific link (in this case local file), thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `window.location.href` will give you full-fledged URL like:-

```
https://www.example.com/index.html

http://www.example.com/index.html
```

etc.

That's why it seems that your `if` condition never becomes true.

Use `indexOf()` like below:-

```
$("#homepage").on("click", function(event) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('index.html') >-1) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true); // recomended to use `prop`
            event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
    }
}); 
$("#aboutUs").on("click", function(event) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('aboutus.html')>-1) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);// recomended to use `prop`
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = 'aboutus.html';
    }
});
```

Reference:-

[indexOf() functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

If you want to disable buttons on only two specific URL'S then use full path in your `if` condition provided by `console.log(window.location.href);`.

Comment: hi is there a easy way to explain how that .indexOf('index.html') >-1 got it to work? or some documentation you can point my way?

Comment: i found that doc also, i just haven't used .indexOf in this way with a link and > -1, ill look over the documentation and hope i can wrap my head around it, thanks

Comment: hi if im understanding it correctly its essentially -1 > -1 to run but why not -1 === -1?

Comment: no `indexOf()` giving the position of that string you are searching and position starts counting from 0. so it will like 0>-1

Comment: i get it now thanks, i was console logging aboutus.html and it was giving me -1, because i was on the index page, so i got confused, why it was working

Comment: @ChristianA   :):). glad to help you. :):)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that what is the value of window.location.href like

```
$("#homepage").on("click", function(event) {
alert( window.location.href);
});
```

than put this value in if condition like:

```
if (window.location.href === 'dummyrul/index.html') {
                $(this).attr('disabled', "disabled");
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
```

Comment: @Christian A try this one